# Is it possible to subscribe to AVAudioSession Category/Mode changed events?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm trying to track and handle all AVAudioSession Category/Mode change events. It is possible to subscribe to those changes?

Answer (score -1):

Add a listener to the [AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification). The [AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey) will contain information on why the route changed. Routes change whenever category/mode changes.